# Optimizing best gain vs capacity/cost

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a sample set of data representing (cost, gain)

```
items = [ (1000, 300), (500, 150), (400, 120), (300, 100), (200, 50), (55, 25) ]
```

I have an algorithm which finds the best combination of multiples of these items to fill a given cost

f(items, capacity, maxCost)

will produce a single entry specifying the most efficient quantities of items constrained by capacity and cost.

```
class BestCombo(object):

    def __init__(self, items, qtyLimit, costLimit):
      self.bestPerf  = 0
      self.best      = None
      self.items     = items
      self.qtyLimit  = qtyLimit
      self.costLimit = costLimit

      self._findBest(load=[], qty=0, cost=0, perf=0)

    def _findBest(self, load, qty, cost, perf):
      idx = len(load)
      if idx >= len(self.items):
        if qty <= self.qtyLimit and cost <= self.costLimit:
          if perf > self.bestPerf:
            self.bestPerf = perf
            self.best = list(load)
        return

      item = self.items[idx]
      maximum = min(self.qtyLimit - qty, (self.costLimit - cost) // item[0])
      for q in range(0, maximum + 1):
        self._findBest(load + [[item, q]], qty + q, cost + item[0] * q, perf + item[1] * q)

items = [ (1000, 300), (500, 150), (400, 120), (300, 100), (200, 50), (55, 25) ]
print("3, 900")
print(BestCombo(items, 3, 900).best)
print("3, 1100")
print(BestCombo(items, 3, 1100).best)
print("3, 3000")
print(BestCombo(items, 3, 3000).best)
print("10, 900")
print(BestCombo(items, 10, 900).best)
print("42, 21000")
print(BestCombo(items, 42, 21805).best)
```

So this produces a 'best' that indicates 3 units of 900 perf is best fit by 3 of the (300,100) item, while 3, 1100 produces a best of 1x500 and 2x300.

While this approach works, it's very slow for non-trivial values.

I've tried a number of variants including a yield-based variant, but they all get slow for some variation (I couldn't seem to come up with a good way to do the yield that didn't generate a ridiculous number of lists in its lifetime)

The "items" list could potentially have 64-90 items max, capacity is unlikely to go much above 255.

I seem to remember in the past using an algorithm to solve this but, perhaps because I'm relatively new to Python and I'm doing this in Python, I'm drawing a blank there.

Is it possible to non-brute force the find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. In the general case this will take exponential time, but one of the dynamic programming approaches may turn out to be practical, especially if you are prepared to round off some of numbers to get an exact answer to a problem with rounded numbers which will be an approximate answer to your problem.